# como mudar a classe de um elemento conforme a posição dos valores dentro de um foreach?

Tags: php, html5

Tenho um menu onde eu listo as categorias. Eu uso o `foreach` para listar e está funcionando tudo certo. Meu código é esse:

```
<?php
$consulta_sub_cat = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_categoriasp");
$sub_cat = $consulta_sub_cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//$sub_cat = str_replace("-"," ",$lista_sub_cat);
?>

<?php
foreach ($sub_cat as $listar_cat) {
?>

    <li class="lv1"><a href="<?= BASE; ?>categorias/audio/<?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?>"><?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?></a></li>

<?php
}
?>
```

Para eu mudar a 1 classe do 1 item do `foreach` fiz assim

```
<?php
$consulta_sub_cat = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_categoriasp");
$sub_cat = $consulta_sub_cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//$sub_cat = str_replace("-"," ",$lista_sub_cat);
?>

<?php

$list = 1;
foreach ($sub_cat as $listar_cat) {?>
<li class="lv<?= $list; ?>"><a href="<?= BASE; ?>categorias/audio/<?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?>"><?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?></a></li>

<?php $list = 2;
}
?>
```

Assim, quando o `foreach` lista o 2, ele muda a classe de `lv1` para `lv2`,  Mas como faço para mudar, por exemplo, o 4 item do `foreach` ou o 6 e assim por diante? Desse jeito so consigo mudar o 1 item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é apenas definir a classe do elemento conforme a posição dos valores no `array`, basta você incrementar o valor de `$list`, ao invés de atribuir o valor doir. Algo como:

```
<?php

$list = 1;
foreach($sub_cat as $listar_cat): ?>

<li class="lv<?= $list++; ?>"><a href="<?= BASE; ?>categorias/audio/<?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?>"><?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?></a></li>';

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Se observar, a classe do elemento é `class="lv<?= $list++; ?>"`, em que `$list++` retorna o valor atual de `$list` e o incrementa logo após.

Mas a melhor solução, ao meu ver, é utilizar o próprio índice do `array`:

```
<?php foreach($sub_cat as $i => $listar_cat): ?>

<li class="lv<?= $i; ?>"><a href="<?= BASE; ?>categorias/audio/<?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?>"><?= $listar_cat->sub_categoria; ?></a></li>';

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Veja que no `foreach` há a instrução `$i => $listar_cat`, em que `$i` será o índice numérico daquele valor no `array`. Valerá 0 para o primeiro valor, 1 para o segundo e assim sucessivamente. Se desejar que a classe inicie-se em 1, basta fazer `class="lv<?= $i+1; ?>"`

Comment: Brigado consegui resolve utilizando o índice como você mencionou

Answer (score 1):

Simplesmente incrementando a variável `$list` antes do final do loop coloca `$list++;`

Comment: se eu fizer assim vai mostra dessa maneira vai ficar assim <li class="lv1"></li><li class="lv2"></li><li class="lv3"></li><li class="lv4"></li><li class="lv5"></li> eu quero que fique somente com a classe lv2 no 3 item e no 6 item do foreach

Comment: If ($list==3 || $list==6){ a sua class}else {outra class}

Comment: @diogoDsa, você não especificou isso na pergunta. Edite-a e escreva EXATAMENTE o seu problema, por favor.

Comment: Tens razão Anderson o Diogo não tinha especificado essa nuance na pergunta.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta